# Laravel5: 'HasManyThrough' using one model and one intermediate table instead of two models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pivot-table, has-many-through

Is it possible to pass an intermediate table as second argument of `hasManyThrough()`? I just want to use a table, not a model. It should be something like:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
   'App\Post',
   'database.table',  <- table instead of model
   'country_id',
   'user_id',
   'id',
   'id'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible to do with an Eloquent relationship.

Easiest way to achieve what you want is to create a new Model that does nothing other than reference your table name:

```
class Example extends Model
{
    protected $table = "database.table"; 
    //or whatever the name of your table is
}
```

You can then do:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
   'App\Post',
   'App\Example', 
   'country_id',
   'example_id',
   'id',
   'id'
);
```

Comment: Forgot to add that you also need to define the relationship between Example and Post

Comment: Yep, I knew this method but was wondering about a solution without extra model. Thx anyway!